# Matrix representation of the $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ $K$ operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, representation-theory, quantum-optics, lie-algebra

I am trying to find the matrix representation of the $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$ $K_{-}$, $K_{+}$ and $K_0$ matrices commonly used in quantum optics defined as $$K_{-}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{a}\hat{a},\quad K_{+}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\quad K_{0}=\frac{1}{4}(\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}).$$
In particular, I would like to know their 3x3 matrix representation. [Mufti, Schmitt and Sargent III](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17149) give a 2x2 matrix representation (and also a 4x4 matrix representation) that satisfies the commutation relations $$[K_{+},K_{-}]=-2K_0,\quad[K_0,K_{\pm}]=\pm K_{\pm}.$$
However, they do not provide details on how they derived these matrices.

I would be grateful if somebody could provide me a derivation of these matrices or simply state the result for the 3x3 case.

Comment: You get that directly from the commutation relations.  Try first getting the $3\times 3$ irrep of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ using commutation relations alone, then just do the same for $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am a student with zero experience in group/representation theory (will learn that in the future) and I am not familiar with the terminology you are using. I do know QM well, so I'd really appreciate a detailed derivation.

Comment: Also see [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holstein–Primakoff_transformation).

Comment: I appreciate your conundrum but it's not right to simply supply the answer.  Look up "adjoint representation" and try to do this for angular momentum first, then do the same for $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They told you $K_-=-J_-$. Did you fiddle with
$$
K_+= \sqrt{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}; \\
K_-= -\sqrt{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}; \\
K_0=   \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} ? \\
$$

Comment: these ones do satisfy the commutation relations. May I ask how you found them?  It would be enough for me to know the derivation of one matrix. Once I know this I can do the other two.

Comment: Standard undergrad QM [spin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins), given your authors' mapping tip.

Comment: Well, I still do not quite understand how you derived them, but I will mark it as accepted answer because I was mainly looking for these matrices. I mean, the link to the spin matrices was not very helpful. I do know how to derive the spin matrices because I know how the angular momentum operators $L_z$ $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ act on the $\lvert \ell, m\rangle$ states. However, for the $K$ matrices above I do not know how they act on states.

Comment: Read the paper. If the spin matrices obey the angular momentum algebra, flipping the sign of $J_-$, as advised, yields for you the algebra of *K*s. So any matrix representation of the *J* s will then produce a matrix representation of *K* s, this way. You are asked about an abstract matrix representation of a given algebra!